# Combining CTEs - Unino two CTEs and join with 3rd CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am looking to combine multiple CTEs to get a result

Here is my first CTE

```
    with CTE_EditLibrary
      as
  (
  select A.[EditLibraryId] as 'Library'
          ,B.[EditLibraryId] as 'SubLibraryId'
      ,B.[EditId]
      from [EnumEditLibraries] as A 
      full join [EnumEditLibraries] as B 
      on A.editid = B.editid
      where A.EditLibraryId in (select editlibraryid from [EditLibraries] where level = 1)
      and  B.EditLibraryId in (select editlibraryid from [EditLibraries] where level = 2)
     order by A.editid
      )
      select * from CTE_EditLibrary
```

I want to join it to the result of these two CTEs

```
with Cte_origins
as
(
SELECT A.editid, A.EditOriginId as 'Origins', B.DisplayName as 'Origin Name',  Null as 'SubOrigins', null as 'SubOrigin Name'
  FROM [EnumEditOrigins] A
    inner join [EditOrigins] B
  on A.EditOriginId = B.EditOriginId
  where A.EditOriginId in (select EditOriginId from [EditOrigins] where level = 1)
  and  editid not in (some values)
  --order by EditId--460, 446
  )
, Cte_suborigins
as
(
  SELECT A.editid, B.ParentEditOriginId as 'Origins', Src.DisplayName as 'Origin Name', A.EditOriginId as 'SubOrigins',  B.DisplayName as 'SubOrigin Name'
  FROM [EnumEditOrigins] A
  inner join [EditOrigins] B
  on A.EditOriginId = B.EditOriginId
  inner join (select EditOriginId, DisplayName from [EditOrigins] where level = 1) as Src
  on B.ParentEditOriginId = Src.EditOriginId
  where A.EditOriginId in (select EditOriginId from [EditOrigins] where level = 2)
  and  editid not in (some values)--2562, 2542
 --order by editid
  )
  select * from Cte_suborigins A
  union all 
  select * from Cte_origins B
```

I am looking at a full join to get editid, origins, suborigins, library and sublibrary for all edit ids.

I can put the CTEs into  #temptables or views and then join however I want to know if this can be done within CTEs without creating and dropping temp tables and views.

If I union 2 ctes and join with 3rd like this, it will throw must have an equal number of expressions

```
With Cte_......
(
.
.
)
 select * from Cte_suborigins A
  union all 
  select * from Cte_origins B
  full join CTE_EditLibrary C 
  on A.EditId = B.EditId
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a third CTE that is the `union` of the `Cte_origins` and `Cte_suborigins` and then `join` that to `Cte_EditLibrary`? Just pile them together in a single `with` and do what you need.

Comment: @George Menoutis - How can I join {Cte_EditLibrary} with the resulting union of {Cte_origins} and {Cte_suborigins} without using Temptable or views..

Comment: @HABO - yes. if I union 2 ctes and join with 3rd like this piled in the same With, it will throw must have an equal number of expressions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, add another CTE, call it D,  that is the union of A and B -> then select from D joined to C.  The reason you get the error if that your code is joining B to C then union to A - that is why the number of columns is not equal.

Comment: Both `Cte_origins` and `Cte_suborigins` have five columns of _data type unauthorized for publication_, so you can (possibly) use `union` (or `union all` if there are no duplicates to be eliminated) to combine them. I'd rather not invest time in guessing what your new invisible code is attempting. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because your unioned selects doesn't have the same amount of columns.
If you join two tables, you get both tables' columns. If you would've replace the `*` with the specific columns, you'd have noticed that the first select in the union cannot access `Library` or `SubLibraryId`, and that's because the join is only between `Cte_origins` and `CTE_EditLibrary`. `Cte_suborigins` gets left behind and has fewer columns than the latter.

Either do the `join` after you've done the `union`, or `join` both with both CTEs

```
 with CTE_EditLibrary as
(
    select 
            A.[EditLibraryId] as 'Library'
    , B.[EditLibraryId] as 'SubLibraryId'
        , B.[EditId]
  from [EnumEditLibraries] as A 
  full join [EnumEditLibraries] as B 
        on A.editid = B.editid
  where A.EditLibraryId in (select editlibraryid from [EditLibraries] where level = 1)
  and  B.EditLibraryId in (select editlibraryid from [EditLibraries] where level = 2)
  order by A.editid
  )
, Cte_origins as(
    SELECT 
            A.editid
        , A.EditOriginId as 'Origins'
        , B.DisplayName as 'Origin Name'
        , Null as 'SubOrigins'
        , null as 'SubOrigin Name'
  FROM [EnumEditOrigins] A
    inner join [EditOrigins] B
  on A.EditOriginId = B.EditOriginId
  where A.EditOriginId in (select EditOriginId from [EditOrigins] where level = 1)
  and  editid not in (some values)
  --order by EditId--460, 446
)
, Cte_suborigins as(
  SELECT 
            A.editid
        , B.ParentEditOriginId as 'Origins'
        , Src.DisplayName as 'Origin Name'
        , A.EditOriginId as 'SubOrigins'
        ,  B.DisplayName as 'SubOrigin Name'
  FROM [EnumEditOrigins] A
  inner join [EditOrigins] B
        on A.EditOriginId = B.EditOriginId
  inner join (select EditOriginId, DisplayName from [EditOrigins] where level = 1) as Src
        on B.ParentEditOriginId = Src.EditOriginId
  where A.EditOriginId in (select EditOriginId from [EditOrigins] where level = 2)
  and  editid not in (some values)--2562, 2542
 --order by editid
)
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    select * from Cte_suborigins A
    union all 
    select * from Cte_origins B
  ) d
  full join CTE_EditLibrary C 
    on d.EditId = c.EditId
```